# Discovering if the "Add to Basket" button has just been clicked

Tags: javascript, php, magento

In Magento 1.9 front end, how can I tell when a product has just been purchased?

When the user clicks the "add to basket" button the page refreshes. I want to display a cart summary momentarily after the page has refreshed, preferably with javascript, or with PHP triggering off some javascript.

What events do I need to look for, or how can I achieve this using Magento's own functionality?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to utilise an observer on `controller_action_predispatch_checkout_cart_add` that stores a session variable that you utilise later.

If you want, you can store details about the product that you've just added, or just set a flag if you then want to show the whole cart or something else.

```
public function logCartAdd(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("sku")->addAttributeToFilter("entity_id", array("eq" => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product', 0)))->getFirstItem();

    if (!$product->getId()) {
        return;
    }

    Mage::getModel('core/session')->setProductToShoppingCart(
        new Varien_Object(array(
            'sku'  => $product->getId(),
            'name' => $product->getName(),
            'qty'  => Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('qty', 1)
        ))
    );

}
```

Then, you can add a block/template to the page, that checks to see if it's set.

```
<?php $_productInformation = Mage::getModel('core/session')->getProductToShoppingCart() ?>
<?php if ($_productInformation): ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // DO SOMETHING
</script>
<?php Mage::getModel('core/session')->unsProductToShoppingCart(); ?>
```